# problems date_format date change, add minutes

Tags: sql, formatdatetime

I have a problem. I do a query like this:

```
"SELECT nome, DATE_FORMAT(data,'%H:%m') as ora_inizio"
```

If I have in the database a dete: 2013-08-01 16:00:00   when I show the dates the date is: 2013:08_01 16:02:00
How is possible?

Comment: try this SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2013-08-01 16:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'); this will result in 2013-08-01 16:00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using MySQL
%m is Month where 1 is January. For minutes you need to use %i.

```
SELECT nome, DATE_FORMAT(data,'%H:%i') as ora_inizio
```

will show 06:00. To shown the full date and time use:

```
SELECT nome, DATE_FORMAT(data,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as ora_inizio
```